# When do I start getting my cartel coins?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I just got a security key for Star Wars the Old Republic. With a security key you receive a free 100 cartel coins each month. When should I expect my first set of coins to come in?

Comment: @TimmyJim You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this thread](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=667100), one user states:

> The 100 Cartel Coins for a Security Key is given on the same date each month, however it does not correspond to your subscription date. It seems to correspond to the day you activated your security key. You can look online under 'My Account' for a list of all of the CC transactions that have occurred for your account. You will see it there.

I've [read on the FAQs](https://help.ea.com/en-us/help/star-wars/star-wars-the-old-republic/friends-of-swtor) that any rewards you've earned will be delivered through in-game mail within 72 hours